# How to prevent this Cyclic polynomial hash function from using a type constraint?

Tags: hash, f#, type-conversion, constraints, rabin-karp

I am trying to implement the [Cyclic polynomial hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) in f#. It uses the bit-wise operators ^^^ and <<<. Here is an example of a function that hashes an array:

```
let createBuzhash (pattern : array<'a>)  =
let n = pattern.Length
let rec loop index pow acc =
    if index < n then
        loop (index+1) (pow-1) (acc ^^^ ((int pattern.[index]) <<< pow))
    else
        acc
loop 0 (n-1) 0
```

My problem is that the type of `'a` will be constrained to an `int`, while i want this function to work with any of the types that work with bit-wise operators, for example a `char`. I tried using `inline`, but that creates some problems farther down in my library. Is there a way to fix this without using `inline`?

*Edit for clarity*: The function will be part of a library, and another hash function is provided for types that don't support the bit-wise operators. I want this function to work with arrays of numeric types and/or chars.

*Edit 2 (problem solved)* : The problem with inline was the way how i loaded the function from my library. instead of

```
let hashedPattern = library.createBuzhash targetPattern
```

I used this binding:

```
let myFunction = library.createBuzhash
let hashedPattern = myFunction targetPattern
```

that constraints the input type for `myFunction` to int, although the `createBuzhash` function is an `inline` function in the library. Changing the way I call the function fixed the type constraint problem, and `inline` works perfectly fine, as the answer below suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the implementation, you are converting the value in the array to an Integer using the `int` function as follows: `int pattern.[index]`

This creates a constraint on the type of array elements requiring them to be "something that can be converted to `int`". If you mark the function as `inline`, it will actually work for types like `char` and you'll be able to write:

```
createBuzhash [|'a'; 'b'|]
```

But there are still many other types that cannot be converted to integer using the `int` function.

To make this work for any type, you have to decide how you want to handle types that are not numeric. Do you want to:

- Provide your own hashing function for all values?
- Use the built-in .NET `GetHashCode` operation?
- Only make your function work on numeric types and arrays of numeric types?

One option would be to add a parameter that specifies how to do the conversion:

```
let inline createBuzhash conv (pattern : array<'a>)  =
  let n = pattern.Length
  let rec loop index pow acc =
      if index < pattern.Length then
          loop (index+1) (pow-1) (acc ^^^ ((conv pattern.[index]) <<< pow))
      else
          acc
  loop 0 (n-1) 0
```

When calling `createBuzhash`, you now need to give it a function for hashing the elements. This works on primitive types using the `int` function:

```
createBuzhash int [| 0 .. 10 |]
createBuzhash int [|'a'; 'b'|]
```

But you can also use built-in F# hashing mechanism:

```
createBuzhash hash [| (1,"foo"); (2,"bar") |]
```

And you can even handle nested arrays by passing the function to itself:

```
createBuzhash (createBuzhash int) [| [| 1 |]; [| 2 |] |]
```

Comment: using the conversion as a parameter solves it, but i don't want to force the user to be forced to choose a conversion method for every input . What i don't understand is why it constraints the type of `a` to `int`, while the int conversion can be used on more types than int. Is there a way to constrain the type of 'a to any type that works with the int conversion?

Comment: @Mutagene : Yes – use `inline`, as the answer directly says.

Comment: @Mutagene It restricts the type to `int` because .NET generics can only have "interface requirement". Here, you'd need "explicit conversion to int requirement". F# can do this, but only for `inline` functions.